# Get selected extensions or no extension returned from bundle search FHIR using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, hl7-fhir, fhir-net-api

I'm totally new to this so pardon my use of terminologies.

I want to know how can i use `SearchParams` so i can select not all but a few selected extensions or dont include any extention in the bundle when i search for a bundle.

Suppose my bundle has 3 extensions

```json
extension: [{
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "ABC",
            "valueId": "00000000-0000-0000-000e-00000000000p"
          },
          {
            "url": "DEF",
            "valueId": "00000005-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
          },
          {
            "url": "HIJ",
            "valueId": "00000005-000K-0000-0000-000000000000"
          }, {..next extention object}]
```

Now what if i only want ABC and DEF in my extension array how can i do that in C# using `Hl7.Fhir`

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me what your flow is. You usually would not search for a Bundle, but a Bundle is returned when you do a search for regular FHIR resources.
`SearchParams` is for setting up the initial search, not for searching in a Bundle when you have received it.
Also, Bundles cannot have extensions themselves, but the entries in the Bundle could have them.

It is not possible on a search to ask a server to include only extensions you are interested in, or to ask it not to include extensions. The only option would be to ask for the summary of a resource, but in that case other data will also be omitted. After receiving a Bundle, you can look for extensions in the resources inside the Bundle, and manipulate them if you want.